# Can I share same bookmarks db among Firefox installations in Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: firefox

I've got a dual-boot system, having WindowsXP-NTFS and Ubuntu-Ext4 partitions. It would be cool if I could use the same bookmarks database in Firefox under Linux and Windows.

How to achieve this? What files should I link and is this expected to work any stable?

Please no web service-based solutions. I have had this idea but prefer my browser data to be stored locally.

Comment: I suggest a fstab binding of the profile directory in Ubuntu to the directory in Windows. I've not posted this solution in the answer, because I'm not knowledgeable about the specifics of Firefox profile - so I'm unsure of success. If you want to try it, tell me the directories of the profiles for both Ubuntu and Windows, and I'll tell you what to do.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) - even though it stores your bookmarks on a server to synchronise with each browser it is installed on (available for Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer) you also have the local data in the browser installation folder

Answer (score 4):

Firefox stores your bookmarks in a database file `places.sqlite` under your [profile 
folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox). Because the database filename [appears to be hardcoded](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/places/src/nsNavHistory.cpp#148), it's probably not designed to be moved to a different location.

Instead of trying to share just your bookamrks, why not share your entire Firefox profile between Ubuntu and Windows? Leave your profile folder on Windows, then [update profiles.ini](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder) on Ubuntu to point to your Firefox profile folder under Windows. I've had good experience transferring Mozilla profiles across OSes, although YMMV. Whatever you do, be sure to make a backup copy of your profile folders before you do anything.

Google shows that some people have had success with this setup. See [this HowTo](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1138477), for example. It looks like certain extensions might have issues doing this, though.