# How to sync Firefox across multiple operating systems/computers. Without Firefox Sync if possible

Tags: firefox, sync

I have one desktop computer with Vista/Ubuntu 12.04 dual-boot, and one netbook with XP.  The netbook is usually far away from the desktop computer (i.e. rarely on the same network).

I would like to share Firefox browsing history and bookmarks across the different computers/operating systems.  Similar to this [Can I share same bookmarks db among Firefox installations in Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27074/can-i-share-same-bookmarks-db-among-firefox-installations-in-ubuntu-and-windows), although multiple physical computers are involved.

Firefox Sync might seem like the obvious option, but I like to solve my problems without creating user accounts and subscribing to new services, if possible/reasonable (even if said services are free).  The question is, is it possible to achieve this without Sync?  Secondly, if possible, is it reasonable?

My first thought was to use Dropbox (which I already have set up on the two computers), and sync configuration files that way.  I'm guessing that would require symlinking in Ubuntu.  Could I then symlink similarly in the other operating systems?  Would this mean trouble if I have different versions of Firefox involved?  What if the two computers are running Firefox at the same time?

Comment: You certainly could do so but I think Firefox sync does exactly what you want. If you absolutely want to go ahead then I could tell you what directory you would need creating symlinks to.

Comment: @nikhil Right, I think I'll probably try Sync in that case.  Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much on other solutions but using **addon** as [Xmarks Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/?src=cb-dl-mostpopular) does the job for me.

> Xmarks provides synchronization and backup services by securely
>   storing your data in your Xmarks web account. You can also access your
>   bookmarks from any web browser or mobile phone by logging in at
>   https://my.xmarks.com